# How to exclude certain assembly/class/method/whatever from solution-wide-aspect?

Tags: c#, postsharp

These links show how to add solution-wide aspects:

1. [Adding Aspects Using XML](http://doc.postsharp.net/xml-multicasting)
2. [Solution-Level Aspects and PostSharp Configuration Files](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/New-in-PostSharp-31-Solution-Level-Aspects-and-PostSharp-Configuration-Files)
3. [Detecting Deadlocks at Runtime](http://doc.postsharp.net/deadlock-detection)

**My question**: assuming added some solution-wide-aspect, how can I exclude certain assembly/class/method/whatever ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AttributeExclude](http://doc.postsharp.net/p_postsharp_extensibility_multicastattribute_attributeexclude) can be used to remove all other instances of the same attribute type from specified elements set.

AutoDataContractAttribute can be multicasted using PostSharp xml configuration file to all classes in `MyNamespace.Customer`:

```
<my:AutoDataContractAttribute AttributeTargetTypes="MyNamespace.Customer" />
```

Say the attribute should not be multicasted types in `MyNamespace.Customer.Excluded` namespace. This could be done by adding:

```
<my:AutoDataContractAttribute AttributeExclude="True" AttributeTargetTypes="MyNamespace.Customer.Excluded.*" />
```

Whole example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration">
    <Multicast xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyCustomAttributes;assembly:MyAssembly">
        <my:AutoDataContractAttribute AttributeTargetTypes="MyNamespace.Customer" />
        <my:AutoDataContractAttribute AttributeExclude="True" AttributeTargetTypes="MyNamespace.Customer.Excluded.*" />
    </Multicast>
</Project>
```

When [AttributeExclude](http://doc.postsharp.net/p_postsharp_extensibility_multicastattribute_attributeexclude) is True then [AttributePriority](http://doc.postsharp.net/p_postsharp_extensibility_multicastattribute_attributepriority) property needs to be specified as well. It is done automatically when using XML but in more complicated cases it could be not sufficient and you would need to specify the [AttributePriority](http://doc.postsharp.net/p_postsharp_extensibility_multicastattribute_attributepriority) explicitly. It could be done by [adding aspects declaratively using attributes](http://doc.postsharp.net/multicast):

```
[assembly: AutoDataContractAttribute(AttributePriority = 1,
    AttributeTargetTypes="MyNamespace.Customer")]
[assembly: AutoDataContractAttribute(AttributeExclude = true,
    AttributeTargetTypes = "MyNamespace.Customer.Excluded.*",
    AttributePriority = 10)]
```